# "Do you know how many books are on the shelf?" "Do you know how many books there are on the shelf?"

Tags: wh-questions, indirect-objects

Usually, positions of subject and verb would be changed, such as the following case.

How many books are there on the shelf?

> Do you know how many books there are on the shelf?

There 1
[By Collins.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/there)

`There is used as the subject of the verb 'be' to say that something exists or does not exist, or to draw attention to it.`

So I thought the role of "there" is like the subject.

And an expected response could be

> There are twelve books on the shelf.

but how about this?

How many books are on the shelf?

> Do you know how many books are on the shelf?

And an expected response could be

> Yes, I know that twelve books are on the shelf.

If it is correct?

*How come both verb and subject remain the same position?

`*The question above is also an example, right?`

Comment: Are you sure the "there" and "are" are the subject and verb?

Comment: I am not sure....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*How many books are there?* asks about the total number of books present. (Collins calls *there is* a subject, but it's really more like a 'dummy subject')

*How many books are on the shelf?* would be more idiomatic if followed by *and how many are on the table?*

When beginning a question with *Do you know?, Can you tell me?* etc, we invert the verb and pronoun or auxiliary verb - so *What time is it?* becomes *Do you know what time it is?* However, your second question can't be inverted because there is nothing to change it with;  the verb *are* is on its own.

Comment: Good answer! nice explaining the inverting part

Comment: @DialFrost Good discussion given by you two!

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know how many books there are on the shelf?

In this case "there" and "are" have to be switched. - @KateBunting (thx for pointing that I'm wrong)

But in this case, the "books" are the subject, the "are" is the verb (So no this is not a valid example to show that the subject and verb change positions).

"There" is an adverb, one of whose definitions is 'used to indicate the existence of something' (Oxford Languages). - @KateBunting

The example given (1st one) is a swap between adverb and verb.

Comment: I see. Books are the subject. I thought the word "there" plays a role of subject and I was wrong.

Comment: @StatsCruncher I may be wrong about the verb, but I'm pretty sure about the subject

Comment: @KateBunting Thx for pointing out that I'm wrong (my bad), but am I right to say that "books" is the subject and "are" is the verb?

Comment: _There_ is not the subject. It is an adverb, one of whose definitions is 'used to indicate the existence of something' (Oxford Languages).

Comment: @KateBunting I added the source of "there" which is used as a subject. It's Collins, though. I still refer to Oxford sometimes.

Comment: @DialFrost It might depend. Some dictionaries would say there is used as a subject, some would say it is not.

Comment: @StatsCruncher Pretty sure at the moment your question (1st example) is a swap of adverb and verb (KateBunting pointed out "there" is an adverb)

Comment: Oh, so it is a different case only with the same word "there"?